# OpenID Connect Signin Page separate endpoint or authorize endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

How does OpenID Connect Authorization Code Flow work? Let's say a user made a request to app.example.com didn't have an access token or had an access token that is invalid. When the app redirected the user to authorization server: auth.example.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=openid&state=STATE&nonce=NONCE

Does the endpoint above have the signin screen? Or does signin happen in a separate endpoint (something like auth.example.com/signin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app redirects the user agent to the Authorization Server, the Authentication Server is supposed to authenticate the user. It can do that by presenting a login screen directly or by deferring to a separate authentication mechanism and/or server and/or screen. The authentication of the user is not prescribed by OAuth and is just something that is specific to the Authorization Server implementation. Both options are possible.